# disallow value to be entered if it already exist 5 times in the colum

Tags: php, database, reference, user-registration

I am trying to find the total of the first 5 users who have a certain id in the database.

Why it is creating totals of all the users and not limiting to the first five?
how do i get the total of the first 5 users with a certain id in the database and leave the rest out ?, here is my code

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amt) AS value_sum FROM users WHERE r1=$id  ORDER BY   
amt DESC LIMIT 5");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2); 
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works?

```
SELECT SUM(amt) FROM (SELECT amt FROM users WHERE r1=$id ORDER BY amt DESC LIMIT 5
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amt) AS value_sum FROM (SELECT amt FROM users WHERE r1=".$id." ORDER BY amt DESC LIMIT 5) AS value_sum");
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The above query should work, i tested on my own table in similar fashion, i dont know why's not working for you. Nevertheless, i wrote a PHP fragment that might help you but it computes the sum in code.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT amt FROM users WHERE r1=$id ORDER BY amt DESC LIMIT 5");
if (!$result2) {
   die("error in query");
}
$sum = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
   $sum += $row["amt"];
}
```

Comment: do i insert As value_sum after i close the query with "
because i cant seam to get it right, could you please give me the code with the tags ""

Comment: im getting error here is my new code
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amt) AS value_sum FROM users WHERE r1=$id ORDER BY users.amt DESC LIMIT 5 AS value_sum"); and here is the error Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\milsoft\members\software\level1.....

Comment: thanks i got it, but now it doesn't pick value_sum

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amt) FROM (SELECT amt FROM users WHERE r1=".$id." ORDER BY amt DESC LIMIT 5) AS value_sum");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2); 
$sum = $row['value_sum'];

and its givning me the error that 

Notice: Undefined index: value_sum in

Comment: its still giving me the total sum of all users, its still not limiting to the first 5. im really stuck here

Comment: thanks man. i have tried everything but its still not limiting